24.04 not recovering after display sleep
the internet is full of people having problems concerning energy saving or power state features. I found some that seemed to be quite similar to my problem but no solution I tried up to now worked.
Ich have Kubuntu 24.04, this is a fresh install. The machine has a 6-core i5-9400 CPU 2,9GHz and a Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630. In the power save settings I allow only the display sleep, not suspend mode or standby.
The problem is, that, when the display turns off for a longer time (I don't know exactly, maybe 1 hour or so) the desktop won't build up again, the screen is flickering and I can see parts of the desktop every 2 seconds or so. This doesn't happen every time the display goes sleeping, only if the display sleeps for a longer time, so I think the display shutting down is not the problem.
I can resolve the problem using STRG+Alt+F7, I get a blank screen with a cursor blinking (I read somewhere something about tty) and then pressing Strg+Alt+F2 and voila, all good.
So, since I have the STRG+Alt+F7/F2 solution this is not as catastrophic as before. But still very annoying.
Is there somebody with the same problem or maybe a solution for this?
I tried without success:

deactivate bluetooth
changing grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=igfx_off"
uninstalling the package xserver-xorg-video-intel

